How to add custom FileUploadHandler to request in ModelAdmin custom view Django 3.2
I need to add custom file upload handler in admin add and change view (using django 3.2). And getting an error.
So far I created custom FileUploadHandler and trying to add to request in my ModelAdmin. Created class in my app\admin.py
@admin.register(MyClass)
class MyClassAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        custom_urls = [
            url('^my_view/$', self.create_model_view, name='my_view'),
        ]
        return custom_urls + urls

    @csrf_exempt
    def create_model_view(self, request):
        request.upload_handlers = [CustomUploadHandler(request)]
        return super().changeform_view(request)

And getting error You cannot set the upload handlers after the upload has been processed.
What am i doing wrong? Where request is started processing?

I created custom class-based view like it mentioned here and getting same issue. So i decided to create a ticket
